# Templated rvalue reference vs non templated compilation errors

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> void f1(T&& a) {}

void f2(int&& a) {}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  f1(i);//This is fine
  f2(i);//This gives compilation error

}
```

Why is same type of calling is having different compilation rules?

templated `f1` accepts `lvalue`, but non templated function doesn't accept `lvalue`. Why?
Doesn't template instantiation of `f1` for int looks like `f2`?

I can fix compilation issues with `std::move`. But above one not understood.

> test.cpp: In function 'int main()': test.cpp:13:7: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'    f2(i);

> test.cpp:7:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void f2(int&&)'  void f2(int&& a) {}

Comment: For a concrete type, `&&` denotes an RValue reference. For a template argument `T`, `T&&` denotes a Universal reference. That's a difference though it's looking very similar. [Scott Meyers: Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) I once made a [mcve] to remind myself (in case some doubts / confusion return to me): [RValue Ref. vs. Universal Ref.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d0fe04a197ed07a)

Comment: These links are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a template context, `T&&` isn't just an rvalue reference, it's a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references).

In a call `f1(i)`, `T` is [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call) as `int&`, and according to [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) rules, `int& &&` becomes `int&`, i.e. an lvalue reference.

That's why it is able to bind to `int x`.

In a non-template context as in `f2`, `int&&` is just an rvalue reference, with no extra magic. It will bind to rvalues only.